# Automatic Code Entry for SMS Authentication in Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

Thank you for taking the time in your busy schedule to view this question.

I am currently doing mobile app development with firebase and flutter. I am using Authentication to implement a login function, and it says that onVerificationCompleted can be used to auto-fill a code in SMS authentication on Android, but it does not work.

When onVerificationCompleted is executed, the message is sent with an 11-digit hash code at the end of the SMS message, but in my app
%LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.
But in my app, %LOGIN_CODE% is your verification code for %APP_NAME%.

I would like to know if anyone knows how to use the automatic login onVerificationCompleted.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using your personal physical device that is receiving the code as the simulator?

Comment: No. Not in use.

Comment: Easiest way is to use a package for this.

Comment: If your simulator device doesn't receive the code, there's no confirmation that the number belongs to you. Firebase can't auto-fill the code in your app if your device didn't receive it, otherwise it defeats the whole purpose. You must manually enter the code to confirm it's your number to maintain system integrity

Answer (score 0):

use **sms_autofill**

```
PinFieldAutoFill(
                codeLength: 4,
                autoFocus: true,
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  lineHeight: 2,
                  lineStrokeCap: StrokeCap.square,
                  bgColorBuilder: PinListenColorBuilder(
                      Colors.green.shade200, Colors.grey.shade200),
                  colorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Colors.transparent),
                ),
              ),
```

Here is an complete Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sms_autofill/sms_autofill.dart';

class SmsVerificationPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SmsVerificationPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SmsVerificationPage> createState() => _SmsVerificationPageState();
}

class _SmsVerificationPageState extends State<SmsVerificationPage>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  AnimationController? _animationController;
  int levelClock = 2 * 60;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController = AnimationController(
        vsync: this, duration: Duration(seconds: levelClock));

    _animationController!.forward();

    _listenSmsCode();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    SmsAutoFill().unregisterListener();
    _animationController!.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _listenSmsCode() async {
    await SmsAutoFill().listenForCode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffF5F4FD),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("SMS OTP AutoFill"),
        titleTextStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(18.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 120,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: const [
                  Text("Verification"),
                  Text(
                    "We sent you a SMS Code",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    "On number: +998993727053",
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                codeLength: 4,
                autoFocus: true,
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  lineHeight: 2,
                  lineStrokeCap: StrokeCap.square,
                  bgColorBuilder: PinListenColorBuilder(
                      Colors.green.shade200, Colors.grey.shade200),
                  colorBuilder: const FixedColorBuilder(Colors.transparent),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text("Resend code after: "),
                Countdown(
                  animation: StepTween(
                    begin: levelClock, // THIS IS A USER ENTERED NUMBER
                    end: 0,
                  ).animate(_animationController!),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 56,
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                //?  use this code to get sms signature for your app
                // final String signature = await SmsAutoFill().getAppSignature;
                // print("Signature: $signature");

                _animationController!.reset();
                _animationController!.forward();
              },
              child: const Text("Resend"),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 56,
            width: 200,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              onPressed:  () {
                //Confirm and Navigate to Home Page
              } ,
              child: const Text("Confirm"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Countdown extends AnimatedWidget {
  Countdown({Key? key, required this.animation})
      : super(key: key, listenable: animation);
  Animation<int> animation;

  @override
  build(BuildContext context) {
    Duration clockTimer = Duration(seconds: animation.value);

    String timerText =
        '${clockTimer.inMinutes.remainder(60).toString()}:${clockTimer.inSeconds.remainder(60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
    return Text(
      timerText,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```